# Values in Derby DB not ordering correctly

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I am trying to only display the top ten values from a Derby database and tried various queries, none of which work. The first query I tried using first is:

```
Select * from scores order by pscore desc limit 5
```

However an error came up. The error code was:

```
Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "limit" at line 1, column 43.
```

I then tried simplifying the query to:

```
Select * from scores order by pscore desc
```

This query works however the order is not correct. For example it orders the top five values as 75, 25, 200, 150, 125, 100

What is the correct query to use for Derby to only display the top 5 values in order?

Comment: Check the datatype of your `pscore` column.

Comment: The data type is varchar

Comment: Right. The list is properly sorted - it's just not the datatype you want it to be. You need to cast the varchar to a numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to derby documentation regarding `limit` [here](http://db.apache.org/derby/faq.html#limit)

Looks like **it is not supported**. Also workaround is given: `use WHERE rownum <= 5` or `FETCH` for version **10.7+**

Corrected query:

```
SELECT * FROM scores order by pscore desc FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Okay I tried it and only displaying 5 rows works. Any way to incorporate the order by clause into that?

Comment: I updated the answer with required corrections to your query

Comment: The following error message appears: `Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "where" at line 3, column 3`

Comment: Please see updated query. Tested locally, should work.